# How to add angular 2 attributes inside a variable in angular 2 typescript class

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

I have a variable 'content' in 'findCharityHome.ts' typescript class as follow.

```
         let content = `
            <b>`+header+`</b>
            <button  style='background-color:#428bca;color:white;padding:5px;'>View Profile</button>
        `;
```

Further, I want to add the following code to above button click event to navigate to another page.But I couldn't find the solution

> this.navCtrl.push(myProfilePage);

This is my full code of the method written in typescript class.

```
addCluster(map){
   if(google.maps){

        //Convert locations into array of markers
        let markers = this.locations.map((location) => {
            let marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            });
            let header = 'some';
            let content = `

            <b>`+header+`</b>
            <button  style='background-color:#428bca;color:white;padding:5px;'>View Profile</button>
            `;  
            this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
            return marker;
        });
        this.markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{imagePath: 'assets/m'});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add angular 2 attributes inside a variable in angular 2 typescript class.In your example, you added a template for your variable and it may work.But typescript attributes will not work here!!